# Create duplicate buttons using Jquery live event

Tags: jquery, duplicates, live

Jquery live is calling in order to duplicate buttons. However this code doesnt give me expected output. Can someone help me to understand what's the wrong here. Im using Jquery version 1.10.2

//HTML

```
<body>

<input class="duplicate" type="button" value="Click" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ext.js"></script>

</body>
```

//JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.duplicate').live({
        click: function(){
            alert('you have clicked');
            $(this).after('<input class="duplicate" type="button" value="Click"/>');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Why you want to use the live event for this?
using simply click on event you get what you are looking for ..

[http://jsfiddle.net/lughino/UZmgX/]

Comment: I forgot ... the live event has been removed from version 1.9 to be replaced with on, as I told you ..

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: @Lughino Thank you for your information. I copied this code from one of the video tutorials and in there it worked well. So version must be the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, don't use live(), it's deprecated. Instead use the on()-method, and delegate the event to the .duplicate-element within a container.
Second you can use .clone() to make a copy of the element instead of typing all that markup again.

```
 $('.container').on('click', '.duplicate', function(e) {
    var $this = $(this),
        clone = $this.clone();

    $this.after(clone);

    e.preventDefault();
 });
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/W7ty8/2/

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Just got some info that live event has removed from version 1.9.